# How to convert null strings to empty string json.net

Tags: c#, json.net

I'm using json.net to serialize a class that has strings, however, when it is converted to json the strings are convert to null, is there a way I could make json.net convert null strings to emtpy strings ('') and not null?

Here is what I currently get

```
var client = {
"FirstName": null,
"LastName": null
}
```

and I want this:

```
var client = {
 "FirstName": '',
 "LastName": ''
}
```

Comment: ryudice, ever find a solution to this?

Answer (score 2):

try:

```
client.FirstName||''
```

This will return '' if `FirstName` is null. Better still create a helper function like this:

```
function null2empty(a){
    return a||'';//You might want to check for strings only before returning
}
```